# How to infer the Poisson rate parameter, given the probability of n events

Tags: poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Suppose I have a Poisson process. Suppose I am given the probability, $p$, that I will observer up to $n$ events. How can I subsequently calculate the implied value of the Poisson parameter?

I am looking for the rate parameter $\lambda$ as a function of $p$ and $n$
$$
\lambda = f(p, n).
$$

What is $f(p, n)$?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Hint: The probability that a random variable takes a value less than or equal to some constant $c$ is given by the CDF.

Comment: @Sycorax the cdf takes the Poisson rate,number of events, and returns the probability.

Comment: I want to give the function the probability and number of events, and return the Poisson rate

Comment: I could probably do this numerically, but was hoping there is a more elegant solution .

Comment: Yes, that's the point of my hint: solve it numerically using the definition of the CDF.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up the question!